# Response.data is a weird object

Tags: angularjs, json, http, asp.net-web-api2, ienumerable

I'm using Angularjs `$http.post` to make a request to a web api that returns an `IEnumerable<>` in `IHttpActionResult`. I'm having a weird issue where the `response.data` is an object with `$id`, `$values`, `$prototype` etc and `$values` is where the actual list is located.

So I have to use `return response.data.$values` to return the actual data which seems a bit awkward to me. I'm certain I'm doing something wrong here. Any ideas?

Thanks

Edit: Posted code

Also, if I'm returning just an object instead of `IEnumerable` then the `data` object directly gives me the data.

```
    [ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<Mastersite>))]
    //[Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Owner/Mastersites")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetMastersitesForOwner([FromBody]JObject data)
    {
        try
        {
            if (data["organisationid"] == null)
            {
                throw new NullReferenceException();
            }
            else if (!StringHelper.ValidIds(data["organisationid"].ToObject<string>()))
            {
                return Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, Errors.MultipleInvalidIdsErrorMessage +
                "[organisationid]");
            }
            else {

                string organisationId = data["organisationid"].ToObject<string>();
                string mastersiteids = data["mastersiteids"] == null ? "" : data["mastersiteids"].ToObject<string>();

                var mastersites = OrganisationService.GetMasterSitesJoined(organisationId);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mastersiteids))
                    mastersites = mastersites.Where(x => mastersiteids.Contains(x.mastersiteid));


                return Ok(mastersites);
            }
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException ex)
        {
            return Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, Errors.MissingArgumentsErrorMessage +
                "[organisationid]");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Content(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, Errors.DefaultErrorMessage);
        }
    }
```

and then the post request

```
OrganisationRepository.GetMastersites = function () {
        var data = {
            organisationid : '93'
        };

        $http.post(apiURL + "api/Organisation/Owner/Mastersites", data).then(
            function (success) {
                alert(success.data.length); // this returns undefined
                alert(success.data.$values.length); // this returns the correct number of results
            }
            , function (failure) { });
    }
```

Here is what the data object looks like

https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1jS0.jpg

Comment: how about you post some code

Comment: Which angularjs version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Angularjs 1.5